How do I access the mock instance type of a export mock?
Using vitest, it is possible to mock an exported module:
import { myFn } from "myFn";

vi.mock("myFn", { spy: true });

See the second tip of the spyOn documentation. This mocks the exported module myFn and then imports a mock of myFn. The imported mock has the type MockInstance<myFn>.
The problem with this technique is that the type of myFn is the actual implementation of myFn, and not the MockInstance that wraps it. The only way I know that the import is a mock is because I know that's how it works. The typing does not show it.
I could find a way to have a correctly typed version of the export:
const myFnSpy = myFn as any as MockInstance<typeof myFn>;

However this does not fix the problem of type of myFn, it only provides a copy with a different type. And on top of that it feels dirty.
How do I make it so that the import's type is a MockInstance<myFn>, instead of being myFn, let alone it's possible?

https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mocked?

@jonrsharpe great, this solves my problem, thank you!
